# Java. Юнит-тесты

Tags: java, юнит-тесты

Здравствуйте, имеется задание: написать приложение, которое выводит на экран текущее время. Также в задании указано: "Код должен содержать все возможные юнит-тесты и создавать читабельный лог файл.". С юнит-тестами ни разу не сталкивался, подскажите где найти подробную информацию про них, нашел только пару статей, но сути особо не понял. Создал Maven проект, в структуре проекта есть папка "test". Там и надо создавать эти тесты? И еще, что имеется ввиду под "ВСЕ ВОЗМОЖНЫЕ юнит тесты"? Что такое лог файла и как он связан с юнит-тестами? Спасибо

Comment: Что имеется ввиду под "ВСЕ ВОЗМОЖНЫЕ юнит тесты" зависит от препода. Потому что вообще говоря все возможные юнит тесты - это на каждую минуту или секунду дня

а вообще про юнит-тесты можно начать с Википедии читать, но лучше в методичке по предмету, так будет лучше соответствовать тому, что препод ожидает увидеть

Comment: Кто придумал эти тесты? Сидит наблюдает как все в поте лица пишут тесты в 100500 раз большие, чем тестируемый код, а потом ещё и тесты тестов и ехидно потирает ручонки.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Добавьте в зависимости мавена:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>junit</groupId>
    <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
    <version>4.12</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

Потом в /src/test/java можете писать юнит, тесты. При сборке проекта они выполняются.
Простой пример с логированием:

```
import org.apache.log4j.FileAppender;
import org.apache.log4j.Logger;
import org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout;
import org.junit.Rule;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.rules.TestWatcher;
import org.junit.runner.Description;

import java.io.IOException;

public class MyClassTest {

    private static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(MyClassTest.class);

    static {
        try {
            logger.addAppender(new FileAppender(new PatternLayout("%d %m%n"), "my.log"));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Rule
    public TestWatcher watchman = new TestWatcher() {
        @Override
        protected void succeeded(Description description) {
            logger.info(description.getMethodName() + " - OK");
        }

        @Override
        protected void failed(Throwable e, Description description) {
            logger.info(description.getMethodName() + " - FAIL");
        }
    };

    @Test
    public void myTest1() {
        //test
    }

    @Test
    public void myTest2() {
        //test
    }

    @Test
    public void myTest3() {
        //test
    }

}
```

TestWatcher - "отлавливает" события по тесту, помимо succeeded и failed можно и другие оверрайдить.

В самих тестах проверяйте код ваших классов. "ВСЕ ВОЗМОЖНЫЕ" - можно понимать как максимальное покрытие.